# Can't open spyder in a new environment in anaconda

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, spyder

I creat a new environment in anaconda to use python2.7.After that, I install spyder, jupyternotebook and ipython for the new environment. But then i found i can't open spyder.

[image]

When I click launch,nothing happened.
And when I want to upgrade python,I also meet a problem:

`UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - backports_abc -> python 2.7*
  - python ==3.6.2
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.`

I don't know what i should do to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried `source activate my_new_enviornment` then `spyder`?

Comment: I create the new environment by NAVIGATOR. And I launch the spyder from  navigator too. Do I still need `source activate my_new_enviornment`?

Comment: I also activate my_new_environment in cmd. But when I want to launch spyder,I meet a problem.`ImportError: cannot import name _psutil_windows`